# Variables panel not showing when debugging any language in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging

I used Python with VSCode for the first time in a while. When I went to debug the script I'd written, I couldn't see any variables in the debug panel. It's not just that none are showing up - there's not even a section where they would be appearing - please see the screenshots below.
When I right click on the three dots at the top of the debug panel, I can see "Watch", "Call Stack", and "Breakpoints", with ticks next to them, but no "Variables" option.
I swear I used to be able to see variables, and everything I'm seeing online is saying that I should be able to, but they just don't seem to be there. At first I thought it was just Python, but I've just tried to debug a simple C program and the same thing happens.
Besides this issue, the debugger seems to work just fine.

What I'm seeing:

[image: What I'm seeing:]

What I'm supposed to be seeing, and what I used to be able to see:

[image: What I used to be able to see, and what I think everyone else can see]

Any information would be really helpful, it must be something daft I'm missing.

To clarify, I've tried a fresh VSCode install, which did not fix the issue.

Comment: try the `...` menu at the top of the debug bar

Comment: @rioV8 "When I right click on the three dots at the top of the debug panel, I can see "Watch", "Call Stack", and "Breakpoints", with ticks next to them, but no "Variables" option." - I said that in the original question.

Comment: you can reset the panel locations, search Command Panel for `reset`

Answer (score 0):

[Solution moved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309552/997587) from [@DCoxshall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15032224)'s question post.

> Just did [a reinstall] and the issue disappeared. If anyone knows what caused it I'd still be interested in information, although the problem is now gone.