# VSCode doesn't show any variable, and stops

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am currently using the VSCode Python debugger to debug HuggingFace SwitchTransformer.

Initially, the debugger worked well and displayed variables and call stacks. However, at some point, it stopped showing variables and only displayed call stacks. Then it stopped showing the message "terminate timeout 2000ms".

Here is a detailed explanation of the problem.

- I am debugging a Python file that uses the HuggingFace framework within a docker container on a Linux machine.
- It is interesting to note that the debugger works well for a lightweight Python file and displays variables, call stacks, and other relevant information.
- I should mention that I am using a Mac and accessing a remote Linux machine. Interestingly, when I access and debug the same file using a Windows machine, everything works as expected.

[image: Screen capture]

Here's the solution that I've tried but didn't work.

- I already re-installed VScode and deleted the related cache in VScode.
- I've re-installed, downgraded, and upgraded the VScode Python extension to a different version.

[Variables panel not showing when debugging any language in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74646338/variables-panel-not-showing-when-debugging-any-language-in-vscode)

I suspect that my Mac environment can cause this problem (maybe memory problem) because,

- The remote Linux machine works well from a Windows machine.
- The debugger works well from my Mac for a lightweight Python file but does not works for the large Python file.

Can the local machine's memory capacity be the reason for this problem? I'm using M1 Mac with 16 GB memory.

I'm using Vscode Version: 1.77.1 (Universal) and Python extension v2023.7.10971005, v2022.8.0.

Comment: This is basically hard to reproduce on other people's machines. If you have the full error log(**OUTPUT** panel), maybe report it on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/new/choose).

Comment: Nothing comes up to the OUTPUT panel.

Comment: You need to toggle the option in the box in the upper right corner of the output terminal.

Comment: I tried most of the possible solutions including asking questions on the GitHub issue of VSCode, but it didn't work.
One solution that I chose was just moving the code base to another Linux machine, and it works.
So basically, I don't have any solution for this right now.